# Apple keeps rejecting my app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, crash-reports

this was apple's message

> 14.3 Details
>
> Your app enables the display of user-generated content but does not
>   have the required precautions in place.
>
> Next Steps
>
> It is necessary that you put all of the following precautions in
>   place:
>
> - Require that users agree to terms (EULA) and these terms must make it clear that there is no tolerance for objectionable content
> - Use moderators to flag and remove inappropriate content and offensive users
> - Users need a mechanism to flag objectionable content and report users generating this content
> - Users need a mechanism to block abusive users
> - Developer must act on objectionable content reports within 24 hours by removing the content and ejecting the user who provided the
>     offending content
> - Developer needs a method for ejecting users who violate the terms of the EULA
>
> 2.1 Details
>
> During review, your app crashed on iPad running iOS 9.3.1 and iPhone
>   running iOS 9.3.1 when we:
>
> Tap "..." On a post
>
> This occurred when your app was used: 
>   - Offline
>   - On Wi-Fi
>   - On cellular network

my app has a privacy policy & terms of service. also it has a more button which you can report things in it.. its the "..." button that crashes 
the thing is it never crashed while trying it on multiple devices iPhones and iPads! i don't get why it keeps being rejected!
first time i sent it without terms of service but now i added it and resent it. but it got rejected again!
the crash log they sent is

```
Version:             1.1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-04-14 19:54:17.17 -0700
Launch Time:         2016-04-14 19:53:55.55 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.1 (13E238)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x182c06e38 0x18226bf80 0x188695288 0x1880a9ec0 0x1880a7fd8       0x187ffafd8 0x188008990 0x187d3a4a4 0x182bbc7b0 0x182bba554 0x182bba984  0x182ae4d10 0x1843cc088 0x187db1f70 0x10011ccb0 0x1826828b8)


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001827a011c 0x182784000 +  114972
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018286cef8 0x182868000 + 20216
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000182711dac 0x1826b0000 + 400812
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001822453f4 0x182244000 + 5108
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000182261e98 0x182244000 + 122520
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018226c248 0x182264000 + 33352
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018225ef44 0x182244000 + 110404
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018225eb10 0x182244000 + 109328
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018226c120 0x182264000 + 33056
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182ae4db8 0x182adc000 + 36280
10  GraphicsServices                0x00000001843cc088 0x1843c0000 + 49288
11  UIKit                           0x0000000187db1f70 0x187d34000 + 515952
12  iFandoms                        0x000000010011ccb0 0x1000c0000 + 380080
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001826828b8 0x182680000 + 10424
```

this is just a part of it.. still it never crashed while i was testing it! please help me! my mind is gonna explode!

Comment: Have you tried installing and running an ad-hoc build. Delete the app from your device before you install it. You need to symblicate the crash log to find out where it was in your app when it crashed

Comment: It will not be possible to determine why this app crashed without 1. a symbolicated crash log (this will show at which class and line in `iFandoms` the crash occurred) and 2. the relevant section of code that crash log will identify.

Comment: Are you testing when your device is offline?

Comment: yes i've tried testing while my device offline,online,on cellular network and it works in all of them! , using ad-hoc. but how to symbolicate the crash log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it turns out its a slight problem with the alert controller.. added some code and it worked!